# $.Callbacks: how to get length of the callback list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
callbacks.add(fn1);
callbacks.add(fn2);
```

Is there any way to get the length of callbacks list. In my case it should be 2.
I've read [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/), but have not got the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like it. The callback `list` array is hidden by scope in the callback function. Take a look at the source. The `list` is defined in the initial callback function and is accessed by the inner callback functions by looking up the scope but the actual callback function only returns the object inside it that holds the defined functions. So unfortunately I see no way to access that `list` so you can see its length and jQuery provides no mechanism either to get the length. Here is the code in jQuery:

```
jQuery.Callbacks = function( options ) {

    // Convert options from String-formatted to Object-formatted if needed
    // (we check in cache first)
    options = typeof options === "string" ?
        createOptions( options ) :
        jQuery.extend( {}, options );

    var // Flag to know if list is currently firing
        firing,

        // Last fire value for non-forgettable lists
        memory,

        // Flag to know if list was already fired
        fired,

        // Flag to prevent firing
        locked,

        // Actual callback list
        list = [],

        // Queue of execution data for repeatable lists
        queue = [],

        // Index of currently firing callback (modified by add/remove as needed)
        firingIndex = -1,

        // Fire callbacks
        fire = function() {

            // Enforce single-firing
            locked = options.once;

            // Execute callbacks for all pending executions,
            // respecting firingIndex overrides and runtime changes
            fired = firing = true;
            for ( ; queue.length; firingIndex = -1 ) {
                memory = queue.shift();
                while ( ++firingIndex < list.length ) {

                    // Run callback and check for early termination
                    if ( list[ firingIndex ].apply( memory[ 0 ], memory[ 1 ] ) === false &&
                        options.stopOnFalse ) {

                        // Jump to end and forget the data so .add doesn't re-fire
                        firingIndex = list.length;
                        memory = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Forget the data if we're done with it
            if ( !options.memory ) {
                memory = false;
            }

            firing = false;

            // Clean up if we're done firing for good
            if ( locked ) {

                // Keep an empty list if we have data for future add calls
                if ( memory ) {
                    list = [];

                // Otherwise, this object is spent
                } else {
                    list = "";
                }
            }
        },

        // Actual Callbacks object
        self = {

            // Add a callback or a collection of callbacks to the list
            add: function() {
                if ( list ) {

                    // If we have memory from a past run, we should fire after adding
                    if ( memory && !firing ) {
                        firingIndex = list.length - 1;
                        queue.push( memory );
                    }

                    ( function add( args ) {
                        jQuery.each( args, function( _, arg ) {
                            if ( jQuery.isFunction( arg ) ) {
                                if ( !options.unique || !self.has( arg ) ) {
                                    list.push( arg );
                                }
                            } else if ( arg && arg.length && jQuery.type( arg ) !== "string" ) {

                                // Inspect recursively
                                add( arg );
                            }
                        } );
                    } )( arguments );

                    if ( memory && !firing ) {
                        fire();
                    }
                }
                return this;
            },

            // Remove a callback from the list
            remove: function() {
                jQuery.each( arguments, function( _, arg ) {
                    var index;
                    while ( ( index = jQuery.inArray( arg, list, index ) ) > -1 ) {
                        list.splice( index, 1 );

                        // Handle firing indexes
                        if ( index <= firingIndex ) {
                            firingIndex--;
                        }
                    }
                } );
                return this;
            },

            // Check if a given callback is in the list.
            // If no argument is given, return whether or not list has callbacks attached.
            has: function( fn ) {
                return fn ?
                    jQuery.inArray( fn, list ) > -1 :
                    list.length > 0;
            },

            // Remove all callbacks from the list
            empty: function() {
                if ( list ) {
                    list = [];
                }
                return this;
            },

            // Disable .fire and .add
            // Abort any current/pending executions
            // Clear all callbacks and values
            disable: function() {
                locked = queue = [];
                list = memory = "";
                return this;
            },
            disabled: function() {
                return !list;
            },

            // Disable .fire
            // Also disable .add unless we have memory (since it would have no effect)
            // Abort any pending executions
            lock: function() {
                locked = true;
                if ( !memory ) {
                    self.disable();
                }
                return this;
            },
            locked: function() {
                return !!locked;
            },

            // Call all callbacks with the given context and arguments
            fireWith: function( context, args ) {
                if ( !locked ) {
                    args = args || [];
                    args = [ context, args.slice ? args.slice() : args ];
                    queue.push( args );
                    if ( !firing ) {
                        fire();
                    }
                }
                return this;
            },

            // Call all the callbacks with the given arguments
            fire: function() {
                self.fireWith( this, arguments );
                return this;
            },

            // To know if the callbacks have already been called at least once
            fired: function() {
                return !!fired;
            }
        };

    return self;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately yes. If you have complete control over your code you could always track what you have added to the list yourself as things are added or fired.

Comment: @Sergey absolutely you can't find it there. Instead you can set a counter to get how many times `.add()` method has been called.